# Why does the file lens not search mounted samba shares?

Tags: 11.10, samba, search, lenses

I've got several samba shares mounted in my home directory (mounted with the "mount.cifs" command).  I can browse the shares just fine.  From Nautilus I can search them just fine.  My question is why doesn't the dash file lens search the mounts as well?  I've also noticed files I open from the shares do not show up as recently used (again in the file lens).  I've Googled around and I've been unable to come up with any thing.

Comment: Do they not show up even when you have mounted those shares? It is sensible not to show them when they are not mounted

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug 
Unity's files lens fails to mount bookmarked remote shares
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-lens-files/+bug/760309

I would also recommend that you file your situation with launchpad.

The importance is low and no fix committed.